# How to observe member variables of a class in MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am trying to observe fields of my class without exposing it. So far, I've tried this:

TaskItemViewModel.kt

```
open class TaskItemViewModel(private val navigator: ITaskNavigator) : ViewModel() {

    private val taskItem: MutableLiveData<TaskItem> = MutableLiveData()

    val title: LiveData<String?> = Transformations.map(taskItem) { it.title }

    val content: LiveData<String?> = Transformations.map(taskItem) { it.content }

    var showCheck: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(taskItem) { it.isCompleted }

    fun setModel(model: TaskItem) {
        this.taskItem.value = model
    }
}
```

ItemListScreenAdapter.kt

```
class ItemListScreenAdapter(private val navigator: ITaskNavigator) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListScreenAdapter.TaskItemViewHolder>() {
    private val TAG = "ItemListScreenAdapter"
    private var dataset: List<TaskItem> = listOf()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: TaskItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
            with(viewHolder.binding) {
            this.viewModel?.setModel(dataset[position])
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    fun updateDataset(dataset: List<TaskItem>) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Updating dataset")
        this.dataset = dataset
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): TaskItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemTaskBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        binding.viewModel = TaskItemViewModel(navigator)
        return TaskItemViewHolder(binding)
    }

    class TaskItemViewHolder(val binding: ItemTaskBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

If I call setModel before inflating the view, everything works fine. However, after the view is inflated, the view is not updated even if `taskItem` 's value is updated. You can be assured that `updateDataset` is called everytime there is a change in dataset.

I want the view to be updated whenever I call `setModel` in corresponding viewmodel. What are the ways to achieve this?

For this viewmodel, I want to use `ViewModel` rather than `BaseObservable`. Therefore, please give your answers according to this.

EDIT:
I have found the solution to the problem.

in `ItemListScreenAdapter`'s `onCreateViewHolder` method, after inflating, I needed to set `LifeCycleOwner` of the binding.

I added the following line after inflating the ItemTaskBinding.

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(parent.context as MainActivity)
```

and the problem is solved and view is being updated.

Comment: Please include the adapter and viewholder implementation at least so that people can check what is causing the problem.

Comment: Don't use a mutable model, or at least call `setModel` after a change.

Comment: Updated my question.